# Getting an fatal error message when trying to render custom blocks on my node twig template

Tags: 8, theming

I'm trying to render or print my custom blocks on my node twig template and currently receiving a fatal error message.

`Argument 1 passed to Drupal\block\BlockViewBuilder::view()`

Here is the snippet of code I'm working on my `.theme` file

```
function iom_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

    $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load(917);
    $block_content = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getViewBuilder('block')
      ->view($block);
}
```

---

`$block` returns `NULL` when I try to do a `dump($block)`

```
$block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load(917);
dump($block);
```

---

Tried using `twig tweak` also to resolve the issue instead of having to pre-process it but no luck

`{{ drupal_block('twitterfeed') }}`

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Check if the variable $block returns NULL

Comment: @AnishSheela just checked and yes it returned `NULL`. Checked the Block ID and it was correct

Comment: It returned null means that there is an error loading that block. You need to check if block exists and corresponding module is enabled.

Comment: enable block in any theme region ,once block rendered using code ,disable it not remove

Answer (score 2):

You can print blocks directly using [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak)

> ```
>   {# No need to configure this block on "admin/structure/block" page. #}
>   <dt>Block:</dt>
>   <dd>{{ drupal_block('system_branding_block', {label: 'Branding', use_site_name: false}) }}</dd>
>
>   {# Bypass block.html.twig theming. #}
>   <dt>Block (without wrapper):</dt>
>   <dd>{{ drupal_block('system_branding_block', wrapper=false) }}</dd>
> ```

<sub>Source: [Cheat sheet](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet-8x-2x)</sub>

Do not use the block's machine name, enable the [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and in block configuration click on Devel tab to get the Plugin ID.

For example, the Site Branding Block has machine name of `sitebranding`, but the plugin ID is `system_branding_block`

[image]

Comment: Tried this also using `twig tweak` to render the block on the `node.html.twig` template. Got an error that the block is missing `{{ drupal_block('twitterfeed') }}`. I have updated my question to provide some screenshots. `Twig Tweak` is installed by the way

Comment: @clestcruz updated the answer, most likely, you're using the wrong id.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
$bid = ?;
$block = \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load($bid);
$render = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($block);
return $render;
```